# What is the best MySQL field type for store Date and Time

Tags: mysql

I have to keep like following entries on my "shift" table. **After store data, I want to caculate total hours( should need to remove meal time from total 
hours), should need to validate shift overlap issues**

```
start date | start time | end date | end time | meal                
2014-10-20 | 18:30      | 2014-10-21 |  6:30  | 30 min
```

what is the best MySQL Field Type for keep above data,

eg: 
combine data+time and store as "Timestamp"
or
dates and times store speratly
or
store as DATETIME

Thank  you..

Comment: And whats the problem your facing? And drop the PHP tag, has nothing to do with PHP

Comment: This depends entirely on what you're wanting to use the data for. Generally the `datetime` field is your best bet as it has semantic meaning.

Comment: @TomWalters thank you for reply, what should be the field type for store "meal"

Comment: I would store a field for start and a field for end, both as datetime. No need to keep them separate, as MySQL has more than enough functions to convert and compare these any old way you like. I assume meal will always be an integer number of minutes, so store that as smallint (or even tinyint, depending on what the maximum possible meal time is), and use it to store the number of minutes.

Comment: @TomWalters uuuhm and what semantics are you talking about? :)

Comment: @user3099298 If it's always minutes, then an `int` should be fine. And @dbf a field type of `datetime` has semantic meaning of a date and time, rather than some arbitrary format, making the code easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

Combine start date / time and select the `datetime` field. Do the same thing for end date / time. And for meal you can select also a `datetime` (**0000-00-00 00:30:00**) or more simply a `time` field (**00:30:00**)